# CPLEX running out of memory without exception

Tags: exception, out-of-memory, cplex

I'm running CPLEX through the COIN/OSI interface (`OsiCpxSolverInterface`). For some large LPs I get an error message `CPX0000  CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.`
Despite the error message, no exception (`CoinError`) is thrown. Looking at the [source code of `OsiCpxSolverInterface`](https://projects.coin-or.org/Osi/browser/trunk/Osi/src/OsiCpx/OsiCpxSolverInterface.cpp) it looks like the return code of `CPXlpopt` must have been 0.

To be clear: my question is not how to avoid the out-of-memory problem. I'm just looking for a way to detect it from my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack that works for me. Setting an error handlers log level to 0 only allows error messages through. Overwriting the MessageHandler's print method then allows to react to the error. This workaround is definitely a hack. If anyone has any better suggestions, I'd be happy to accept a different answer.

```c
class ErrorCatchingCoinMessageHandler: public CoinMessageHandler {
public:
    ErrorCatchingCoinMessageHandler()
        : CoinMessageHandler() {
        // Would be nice to also overwrite setLogLevel to avoid later changes
        // but its not virtual
        setLogLevel(0);
    }

    virtual int print() __attribute__((noreturn)) {
        CoinMessageHandler::print();
        abort(); // or throw a CoinError
    }
};

// Use it like this

lp_solver->passInMessageHandler(new ErrorCatchingCoinMessageHandler());
```